# I cannot seem to be able to apply a light font weight to react input and select option elements

Tags: css, reactjs

This is my code. Other elements in the same component are accepting the light font weight assignment, whose value is 300

```
neworder {
  height: 76.7rem;
  width: 55rem;
  & input,
  select {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 42.1rem;
    height: 3.9rem;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 1rem;
  }
```

this is the html

```
<form>
<select style={{ color: '#707070', fontWeight: 'lighter' }}>
<option value={placeHodler}>{placeHodler}</option>{areas.map(area => (
<option key={areas.indexOf(area)} value={area}>
{area}</option>))}
</select>
<input type='text' placeholder='ESTATE/APARTMENT NAME'></input>
<input type='text' placeholder='HOUSE NUMBER'></input>
<p className='neworder-price-value'>Total Pice, including delivery: <span>{totalPrice}</span>
</p>
<button type='SUBMIT'>PLACE ORDER</button>
</form>
```

Comment: could you paste the html too?

Comment: @LuisFernandoMontoya I have added the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just think you have typos in your CSS rules, try:

```
.neworder {
  height: 76.7rem;
  width: 55rem;
}

input, select {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 42.1rem;
  height: 3.9rem;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is still not working. Strange thing is that if I set the weight to 700, it works well, it just does not respond to 300, while other elements are responding well

Comment: what font are you using?

Comment: I am using Montserrat

Comment: check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-wildflower-5pg0s it worked to me. Notice I removed the fontWeight from the select element

Comment: Thank you, I realized the problem was that the select and input elements were not inheriting the global font size. I removed fontWeight from select and included the font family in the styling of the elements